# Embedded CSS in HTML - Change Word Color based on different words

Tags: html, css, zabbix

### My Situation

I am currently trying out the new E-Mail function that comes along with the new Zabbix major update 5. In there, you can format your E-Mail with HTML.
I already built something and in that HTML template there is a header like this:

`<h3 align="center"><font color="white">Severity: {TRIGGER.SEVERITY}</font></h3>`

`{TRIGGER.SEVERITY}` is a Zabbix Macro that shows the severity of the alert send via Mail.

What I'd love to see is the color of this macro change based on the Severity level. So, if the mail gets send out while "Information" is staying there, i want it to be f.e. green, while when "Disaster" is in there, i want it to be red.

---

### My Question

Is this possible? And if yes, how will I able to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for every comment!

Greetings,
Josh

Comment: Hey. I don't know Zabbix, however if you have something like: `if ({TRIGGER.SEVERITY} == 1) { <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Severity: {TRIGGER.SEVERITY}</h3> } if ({TRIGGER.SEVERITY} == 2) { <h3 style="text-align: center; color:green;">Severity: {TRIGGER.SEVERITY}</h3> } ...` so on so forth it should work

Comment: @Linux4Life531 Can you just add if statements into plane html? :o 
I thought of that at first, but thought that you either need to implement a php section to use if statements or have to use some specific css code. 
But I guess that i will give that a try :D Thanks for now, i'll tell you if it worked.

Comment: Got it - we can use javascript! :D

Comment: Try `if ({TRIGGER.SEVERITY} == 1) { document.write("<h3 style='text-align: center; color:white;''>Severity: {TRIGGER.SEVERITY})</h3>";
} 
if ({TRIGGER.SEVERITY} == 2) { document.write("<h3 style='text-align: center; color:green;''>Severity: {TRIGGER.SEVERITY}</h3>"); 
}`

Comment: So, something like ```<h3 align="center" id="severity"><font color="white">Severity: </font><span style="test()">{TRIGGER.SEVERITY}</span></h3>```

```<script> function test() { if ({TRIGGER.SEVERITY} == Information ) { document.getElementById("severity").style.color= "red"; } if ... } </script>``` 

? :D

Comment: The use of font tags and align="center" is now non-standard gone. We now use CSS. This means you can just put style="text-align: center; color: white", instead of the font tag, as I have done in my code. Otherwise your code should work!!!

Comment: I implemented your code, but i can't test it right now cause our test zabbix db is down atm.. i will get back to you as soon as possible. Thanks again for now! :)

Comment: I was able to test both solutions, and none of them worked :/ 
Your solution was just standing hardcoded in the mail and mine only colored the severity level in black :'D

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS and assign a CSS class using `{TRIGGER.SEVERITY}`. Then define the CSS class with your desired colour, e.g. a template could look like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .sev_Disaster {
    color: #E45959;
  }
  .sev_High {
    color: #E97659;
  }
  .sev_...
</style>

<h3 align="center"><span class="sev_{TRIGGER.SEVERITY}">Severity: {TRIGGER.SEVERITY}</span></h3>
```

Notice the `class="sev_{TRIGGER.SEVERITY}"` which will turn into e.g. `class="sev_High"` which is defined in the `<style>` block above.

Another way would be to use different Media types (same transport but different templates) for each severity - this would give you much more freedom but you'd have 6 mostly similar templates and thus changes would've to be implemented in all 6 of them.